# How to handle OldEarthOrientationDataWarning warning to update IERS table when astroplan module is imported (python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, warnings

With one of the modules I'm currently using ([astroplan](https://astroplan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) it has to download a IERS table in order for the timings in it's Observer objects to be accurate. (I'm using it to workout sunrise/sunset times etc). Problem is after 14 days or so, the table becomes out-of-date and a new one needs to be downloaded. Once the table is out-of-date an [OldEarthOrientationDataWarning](https://astroplan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/astroplan.OldEarthOrientationDataWarning.html#astroplan.OldEarthOrientationDataWarning) warning is raised when the module is imported.

What I'd like to do, is detect if the warning is raised, and update the table if there is a warning.

Normally the module is imported using:

```
>>> from astroplan import Observer
```

I know how to update the table manually using:

```
>>> from astroplan import download_IERS_A
>>> download_IERS_A()
>>> from astroplan import Observer
```

I also know that Python has a [warnings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html) module, from which I think the catch_warnings function is what I need to be using. There are quite a few examples on how to get code to ignore deprecation warnings, but I don't want to hide the warning. I just can't seem to get my head around how to lay it out to get it to do what I want.

I'm using Python 3, and need the code to work on UNIX machines.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've sorted it myself. I'll post the code below in case someone else ever wants to do the same thing.

```
import warnings

# Set up the thing to catch the warning (and potentially others)
with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as w:
    # import the modules
    from astroplan import Observer
    from astroplan import OldEarthOrientationDataWarning
    #One want to know aout the first time a warning is thrown
    warnings.simplefilter("once")

#Look through all the warnings to see if one is OldEarthOrientationDataWarning,
# update the table if it is.
for i in w:
    if i.category == OldEarthOrientationDataWarning:
        # This new_mess statement isn't really needed I just didn't want to print
        #  all the information that is produce in the warning.
        new_mess = '.'.join(str(i.message).split('.')[:3])
        print('WARNING:',new_mess)
        print('Updating IERS bulletin table...')
        from astroplan import download_IERS_A
        download_IERS_A()
```